# how to understand bindkey

Tags: zsh, keyboard-shortcuts

Comming from this page with information on how to customize zsh I encounter this

```
# oh wow!  This is killer...  try it!
bindkey -M vicmd "q" push-line
```

I'm not able to find a man page for bindkey, nor understanding what is the key being binded, what does `-M` means and what is `vicmd`.

So I've no idea how to know whats the beautifier killer feature :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
% type bindkey
bindkey is a shell builtin
```

So its documentation is in the zsh manual, not in a man page of its own. Although there's a `man zshbuiltins`, the `bindkey` builtin is not documented there because it's part of a semi-autonomous piece of zsh, the line editor zle, and so it's documented in `man zshzle`.

You can find the documentation by running `run-help bindkey` in zsh, or pressing <kbd>M-h</kbd> while the cursor is on a `bindkey` command. This requires `run-help` to be properly set up, which for some reason is not the case by default: it's an alias to `man`. To get a useful `run-help`, put these lines in your `.zshrc`:

```
unalias run-help 2>/dev/null
autoload -U run-help
```

Alternatively, use `man zshall`. Or if you're browsing a hypertext version of the manual, use the [functions index](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions-Index.html#Functions-Index), which also lists builtins.

---

`vicmd` is the [keymap](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Keymaps) used in vi command mode. [`push-line`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-push_002dline) is an [editor widget](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Standard-Widgets), which have [their own index](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Editor-Functions-Index.html#Editor-Functions-Index). So this command makes `q` “pause” the current line in vi command mode (for some reason this feature, which is indeed useful, is only bound to a key by default in emacs mode).

Comment: I upgraded omz yesterday. I put `unalias run-help` in my .zshrc (the line after `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`) and it gave me this error: `/home/dan/.zshrc:unalias:86: no such hash table element: run-help`. That might mean you don't need to do that step anymore. But when I run `run-help bindkey`, it prints two lines: `bindkey\n    See the section \`Zle Builtins' in zshzle(1).` Is that what I'm supposed to see?

Comment: @DanielKaplan zsh defines an alias called `run-help` by default, but I guess recent versions of omz remove the alias. Calling `unalias` on an alias that doesn't exist is harmless except for the annoying error message, so I've edited my answer to suppress that message. As for the documentation of `bindkey`, indeed `run-help` is unfortunately not smart enough to see that it's just a cross-reference to another part of the manual and it should show the content of that part.